# How i can made TextBox like this

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

[image]

How i can made TextBox like this in Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Something like that can easily be done by putting an `<Image />` and a `<TextBox />` inside of a `<StackPanel />` with the stackpanel's `Orientation` set to `Horizontal`.

Comment: When I do these types of inputs, I just customize a TextBox style template, and pass in the icon path through the `Tag` property at the instance level so I can do something like `<TextBox Tag="littlemaniconpath"/>` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `UserControl` that has an `Image` and a `TextBox` in it. You'd need to declare a `string Text DependencyProperty` and a `string ImageSource DependencyProperty` to data bind to. Your XAML would look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
</Grid>
```

If you're not familiar with creating `DependencyProperty`s, then you can find out how to do it in the [Custom Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.